# Representing a windows service polling a database in UML

Tags: database, service, uml

I have a windows service which continuously polls a database to fetch data from it. How to represent this scenario in UML?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Activity diagram, where one action is when the service sleeps and another action is when the service polls the database, and you can connect them in a loop.

Another possibility is to use a State Machine diagram with two states, one idle, one polling, and in the polling state have a `do` action that calls the database